# How can I get Ubuntu (17.10) to logout and suspend on closing the lid?

Tags: suspend, laptop, session

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with the Gnome desktop and want to force a user logout before going into suspend mode whenever someone closes the lid.
From my search in this forum it looks like most folks see this exact behavior while I don't. On my machine the user gets simply locked, I like the session to be completely logged out.

Is there a setting I can change, maybe in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`?

Comment: Interesting question. There are a few ways to suspend. I think the systemd suspend service could be modified to call logout command. However an inadvertent suspend might cause loss of changes to opened files. These are just some brain storming thoughts, I haven't tried anything like this before.